# Spring-Boot with React JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, thymeleaf

As the title says I'm dealing with Spring Boot and react JavaScript at the moment. I would really appreciate it if someone would be able to answer me on a few small questions.

1. I created a separate react project using vscode IDE. Now I need to add it to my Spring Boot application. I have used Eclipse to code my Spring Boot application.Can I just transfer the react JavaScript files to the Eclipse IDE? Will it work like that?
2. Also, to configure these two together I read that I should use thymeleaf. What are you thoughts on this and do you think its better to use this.

Comment: check this course on Udemy https://www.udemy.com/full-stack-project-spring-boot-20-react-redux/learn/v4/overview

Answer (score 0):

You may not require to transfer any code from one IDE to another. I assume both this front-end(react) and middle layer(spring boot) are two separate project.

You can still run the boot project in eclipse pointing to same localhost(for development) with a different port and front-end in a different port.

I found this [example](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/19/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot) is quite useful

Comment: Thank you very much! I have another small doubt that i would like cleared from your answer. My react application runs on localhost:3000 and my spring application runs on localhost:8080. Im not very familiar with this so im sorry if this is a dumb question. I cant do this in Two IDE's right? Am I suppose to run my react app on vscode and then run my spring app on java spring?  Or do i export all the files from my vscode project and add all of them into the Spring project?

BTW thank you so much for the help!  Really appreciate the support :D

Comment: You can run them separately in two ide(s). In production that is how it works, front end code is deployed in some machine and so is backend code.You can run the front/backend -end in two separate ide(s) but port need to be different

Comment: StackOver flow is telling me not to say thanks but i have to XD thank you for the help!

Comment: check this course on Udemy https://www.udemy.com/full-stack-project-spring-boot-20-react-redux/learn/v4/overview

Comment: Hello again, Im not sure if its ok to ask another question here so ill be short. https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ 
In this documentation they have shown that its in the same package as i understand. Can you tell me if its the same way or what i have to change if im doing it seperately?

Comment: @georgesvan thank you so much! I will definitely check it out! Im new here and im very glad theres so many people out here to help. Thanks guys

Comment: Yo can merge both spring boot and react in same package.

Comment: @georgesvan oh ok! thanks so much. i will do it that way! :D

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to think about your React and Spring apps as of two completely separate applications. The React app is the "front end" application that is displayed to the user and holds the logic for all the user interactions. Spring boot is the "back end" service that holds the state of your application and helps you to save and fetch data.

To get started try building and running your React app from something like [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). It is easy to set up a local development server. You should also understand that the React app that you get after building is just some static files - so you can host them very easily and cheaply without need for an actual server. I personally use S3.

Now to your Spring application. This is your 'API' layer and you should read about using APIs for example here: [Official Spring Docs](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/) .
You still theoretically CAN bundle both together and serve the React bundle out of the Spring static files directory but you will likely find this will get awkward fast. [Here is an example of someone doing exactly this](https://medium.com/@pietroghezzi/spring-and-react-js-the-easy-way-5abe8a529058)

As for Thymeleaf - in the React world you will likely end up using JSX for your templating needs. It is a wonderful way of closely integrating your js and html code and creating highly reusable components.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can build an automated container deployment. This allows you to test, build and deploy your backend and frontend with every git push to your server.

For example google some keywords: Kubernetes, Docker, Gitlab CI.
There are much more solutions and platforms to build a system for automating deployment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into these topics. Also, do you think its better to do this or should i just add my react application files to my spring project? 
As per coding standards, do you think its better to have my react application files in my spring project? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: It is definitely state of the art to build a pipeline for automated deployment because it brings a lot of advantages like more scalable, manageable and much more. But of course, it takes more effort to set it up.